# Get user's most published categories

Tags: posts, categories, users

I am working on listing all users similar to the [Users](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users) page here on SE.

When listing each user, I want to add their 2 categories they have published most into. All categories are within `Posts`.

Performance is essential, therefore I've come up with a sufficient solution:

1. Make a function (with `$user_id` as argument) that returns category name of the user's two most published categories.
2. Create a daily `wp_schedule_event()` WP Cron that uses the above function and gets all users respective categories and finally adds it to each user's metadata via `add_user_meta()`.
3. Simply get the users' categories via `get_user_meta()` on the Users page.

Currently, I have the cron and metadata codes ready, **all I am missing is the function that returns the users top 2 categories**. Can you help with this function?

Comment: Are you saving category id's or names? And as array or string?

Comment: @Ervald Category names. Array or string, it does not matter.

Comment: Gave you an answer with meta categories as array.

Comment: @Ervald My apologies, with "saving category id's or names", I misunderstood your question, I do not currently have category names/id's saved in the user's metadata. My aim is to make a function to *get* the user's top 2 most published categories. I think if you reread my question, I believe it is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done easily with `$wpdb`, here's my approach:

```
function GetTop2CategoryByUser($user_id, $taxonomy){
    global $wpdb;

    $results=$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
     "
       SELECT      tt.term_id as category, COUNT(p.ID) as count
       FROM        $wpdb->posts p

       JOIN        $wpdb->term_relationships tr 
                   ON p.ID = tr.object_id

       JOIN        $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt
                   ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
                   AND (tt.taxonomy = %s AND tt.term_taxonomy_id != 1)

       WHERE       p.post_author = %s
       GROUP BY    tt.term_id
       ORDER BY    count DESC LIMIT 2
    ",
    $taxonomy,
    $user_id
   ) );
 return $results;
}

// Get user's top 2 published categories
$user_top_cat = GetTop2CategoryByUser($user_ID,$taxonomy)

// $results should return
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 4
            [count] => 8345
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 3
            [count] => 45345
        )
)
```

It's slightly faster retrieving the category ID's instead of names.

Comment: I am not sure if this is working correctly. I ran this with a random $user_id and this is is the returned array: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 2412 [count] => 808 )[1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 28 [count] => 625 ))... If term_id is category ID, then we definitely do not have category ID's equaling 2412 or 28. Or am I missing something? Please advice. Btw, I will edit your answer to wrap it into a function with $user_id as argument.

Comment: My mistake, wp uses taxonomy relationship for the menu as well, I've edited the query and added this line `AND tt.taxonomy = 'category'` where 'category' is the name of the taxonomy, if you have a custom taxonomy change it.

Comment: Thank you for the update, although it appears there are still problems. When I run $user_top_cat = GetTop2CategoryByUser($user_ID,'category'); -- I get an array with two term_ids (category IDs). The problem is that these two aren't the users most published categories. It is correct that the user has published **in** those categories, **but** it is definitely not the user's top 2 most published categories. I tried it with several users and the same result unfortunately. Can you please confirm this? Is there an issue with the query?

Comment: There were few problems with the query (mainly the count) which gave wrong results. Edited the code, hopefully you get the desired results. On my local testing it works.

Comment: Works great, thank you very much for taking the time to write this code. Can finally implement this into the platform! Out of curiosity, how heavy is this query? We have thousands of users. I am thinking of running this once per day...?

Comment: Need to bother you once more. Ran this query on all users and stored the returned values in the users metadata. Around 10% of the users, it didn't work correctly. It appears it selects category ID 1 (Uncategorized) for one of the arrays instead of the correct category ID. For example, see this: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [category] => 16 [count] => 6 )[1] => stdClass Object ( [category] => 1 [count] => 2 )) -- looking at [1], we can see that the cat ID is 1, when it should have been 17. The count is correct though, I've checked which cat the user has published in manually. Any ideas?

Comment: Changed the code it should skip category 1 now. As for optimization, how many categories do you have?

Comment: Works fine, it skips category 1. Thank you! Regarding categories, around 12 categories, but **many** users.

Comment: Then you can store an array of the categories as custom meta for each user with the count. Then for updating on every post_insert run a function to update the custom meta by adding/removing by 1 to the count of the corresponding category. This way you will never have to do that query above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

  $key = 'user_top_categories'; // User meta key for the top categories
  $single = false; // Array or String
  $top_categories = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single );

  foreach($top_categories as $top_cat){

     $term = get_term_by('name', $top_cat, 'category');
     $term_link = get_term_link( $term );

     echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '">' . $term->name . 
          ' ('. $term->count .')</a></li>';

  }

?>
```

Comment: I believe you may have misunderstood my question. I want a function to *get* the user's top 2 most published categories. I think you are doing something else in your answer.

Comment: Check my new answer.